# Vertically/Horizontally Center Image of Unknown Size with Anchor Hover State

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image (both horizontally and vertically) that has unknown dimensions. This image maybe larger then the container's size (101x84) so I need to constrain the image with `max-width` and `max-height`. Lastly, the image needs to have a hover state where an icon will appear in the middle of the container if the user hovers over the image.

Currently, my code meets all of the above requirements except that I cannot vertically align my image. I have tried following other guides, such as changing the img to `display:inline-block` but then I loose my horizontal center alignment.

If possible, I'd rather not use javascript/jQuery unless absolutely necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/uNvSU/1/

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery/javascript?

Comment: I'd rather not use jQuery/JS unless that is the absolute only way.

Comment: have you tried using display:table-cell with valign:middle and center?

Comment: @ntgCleaner That works :) Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display:table-cell` and then use `vertical-align:middle` and then either `margin:0 auto;` or `text-align:center`

That should do you right.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment so I am putting this as a seperate answer.

`display:table-cell` is not supported by IE7. So if you have to support IE7 you can add this to make `display:table-cell` work:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7 ]><table><td><![endif]-->
<div>                   
 ...
</div>
<!--[if lte IE 7 ]></td></table><![endif]-->
```

Also six different ways of vertical centering without javascript is discussed over here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/